# Controls missing from Windows form on 1 PC only. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

I have a C# Windows Form application that displays properly on 25+ different PCs. But on one PC there are several controls that are missing from the form -- as if the visible property was set to false (but it is not). The missing controls include a listbox, textbox and a button. Other controls on the same form display properly and include a few labels, textbox and datagridview. All of these controls (the ones that are missing and the ones that display properly) reside in nested splitcontainers. Application has been uninstalled and reinstalled several times. PC has all latest drivers and Windows updates installed.

How do I proceed in debugging such an unusual bug? Anyone have any ideas? Numerous Google searches turned up no help.

Comment: Maybe there is some [GDI resource leak](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak/).

Comment: what sort of controls are missing?

Comment: @BugFinder - "The missing controls include a listbox, textbox and a button."

Comment: To be clear - you're talking about standard windows forms controls from .NET Framework - not any third party controls?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes, you are correct. No third party controls. Just the stock Windows Form controls.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I will check into the GDI resource leak possibility, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Then I'd concentrate first on working out *what is different about that one PC*. Try to find some property (or properties) that are true of this one PC but untrue of the others. I'd first be thinking about graphics (e.g. graphics cards, monitor resolutions, number of monitors, etc) and wondering whether the controls are *there* but positioned differently - not within the visible region.

Comment: Other DPI setting combined with "bad" anchoring/docking of the missing controls ? Checking the Autoscalemode on the form could also be worth while, atleast if the issue is indeed DPI-related

Comment: Are all the PC have exactly the same version of Windows? There may be some differences in Windows SDK, so e.g.  in Windows 10, version 1607, the XAML framework provides a built in Boolean to Visibility converter, but not in earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question, I have nested SplitContainers. Apparently, with numerous nested (Panel and SplitContainer) controls, the thread can run out of kernel stack space due to the many positioning commands being sent to each nested control, and the positioning of controls fails silently. Which is what was happening to me. My form had 6 SplitContainers nested in one way or another.

I followed the guidance [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/953934/deeply-nested-controls-do-not-resize-properly-when-their-parents-are-r) for overriding the nested container control's OnSizeChanged event, and it solved my issue completely. I only overrode the 6th SplitContainer and left the other 5 using the stock Windows SplitContainer control (as suggested in the article).

Still, I find it unusual it only occurred on one PC, and that PC was an expensive Sager laptop with a very high-end graphics card.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/953934/deeply-nested-controls-do-not-resize-properly-when-their-parents-are-r)